# Is there a tool for Visual Studio which can show the list of all called functions?

Tags: visual-studio

When debug application, it may be usefull to see in what sequence methods are called. It is possible to write Debug.WriteLine("Called MethodName") in earch method but there are big number of methods in my project.

Is there tool that logging method calls?

Comment: You can check [call stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx).

Comment: @NaveenBhat but callstack only shows you where you currently are. Doesn't show a history

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Runtime Flow](http://www.svprogramming.net/runtime-flow/index.html) (developed by me) shows all function calls in a .NET application.

Comment: @sergey-vlasov Nice tool, I'm missing a feature however. Would be great if it could output the function calls in plain text, then it would be possible to diff two executions (with different input data). The would be great for debugging!

Comment: @salle55 It indeed requires some manual work, but you can use the "Copy as text" button in the flow window to copy an execution as plain text to the clipboard.

Comment: @SergeyVlasov I tried to use the trial version. I had class project which is deployed into different solution and debugging it doesn't show any entry in flow window. I'm using debugger as an attached to process (Ctrl +Alt + P). Will it work in this case too?

Comment: @Vishnu Runtime Flow doesn't use Visual Studio debugger. You need to start your process by Runtime Flow and make sure that monitoring filter includes your class project dll.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, the [Visual Studio Call Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx) window already implements this.

However, if you really wanted more information you can always look in to adding [Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx) information.

Comment: CallStack window shows only call stack but not all called functions since application was runned. Tracing class may be usefull but I need an environment tool.

Comment: @EugeneMaksimov: You can use [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx)...

Comment: I mean Visual Studio Environment. Maybe there is add-in wich has this feature.

Comment: DebugView only spits out debug msgs, its useful if you dont have the code but want to see any debug messages the app might be spewing

Answer (score 0):

You could use an AOP (aspect oriented programming) framework to make your life a bit easier.

There is a worked example of how to use PostSharp to log method calls here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/337564/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-Using-Csharp-and-PostS

Comment: Maybe not a tool, but it's a quick and unobtrusive way of logging all method calls in an application