# How to get the entry point of a project code in C#

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I have been assigned a project in C# on Visual Studio 2017.
Assuming that I don't want to know which method usually executes when an application is run, I want to find out manually by debugging into the code and see the code executing line by line. 
I'm also new to debugging so any kind of help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You could try to start the debug in steb-by-step mode pressing the F11 key (if you haven't remapped it)

Comment: Did you try to search google? there are tons of articles

Comment: for example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx

Comment: Entry point of application is always static method `Main`. You can search it from the project. Some project types will generate `Main` method during build

Comment: So if I dont set any breakpoints, and run the debugger, it'll automatically take me to the start of the code?

Comment: @Fabio, but my Program has two private static Main() methods in two different files. How to figure out which is the starting point?

Comment: Check project properties "Application" tab - "Startup object" selection

Comment: I started debugging and then checked the call stack. Got my problem solved now.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415084/is-there-a-tool-for-visual-studio-which-can-show-the-list-of-all-called-function

Comment: @imujjwalanand, Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, if so, would you please post your solution as the answer(not the comment), so you could mark it as the answer and it also help other community members who get the same issue as yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While debugging, take a look at the call stack, and you'd get what is called first and what awaits.
Solved the problem for me.