# How to track the number of times a method is called

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

I need to count the number of times each method is called when the project is run.

Also I need to know both the production and the dev mode, whatever tools code or something it can count for me.

I use C# .NETcore vso2017 Enterprise

Comment: [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) FTW!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415084/is-there-a-tool-for-visual-studio-which-can-show-the-list-of-all-called-function

Answer (score 4):

You could use the Performance Profiler in Visual Studio (Analyze > Performance Profiler...). In Available Tools, check Performance Wizard. Start (choose Instrumentation method).

When the profiling is finished, it should show you the Summary view of the profile. Change the Current View dropdown to Functions. This should list all the functions that were hit during execution along with the number of calls (plus time spent, etc).

Comment: This cannot be used outside VS, and OP states: "both of production and dev mode"

Comment: True. But the OP states that he is using VS2017 and it is indeed a tool that can analyse what they want. I wasn't entirely sure what OP meant by "production or dev mode". If "mode" means "environment", it is possible to run VS in a production Windows environment. If that is not possible/preferable, yes, OP will need to use a different tool.

Answer (score 3):

Create a static variable outside the function.
Increment it every time function gets called.

```
public static int numberOfinvokes = 0;

public void myMethod()   
{   
    //do something;    
    numberOfinvokes +=1; 
}
```

Comment: it's not thread safe

Comment: Then make it threadsafe `Interlocked.Increment(numberOfinvokes)`