# Is there a way to get a call stack when nothing errors in asp.net core app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stack-trace, callstack, orchardcore

I downloaded [OrchardCore](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore) project from Github. I am trying to understand the lifecycle of each request through code.

How can I get a call-stack of a complete request so I can follow the code to see what takes place at runtime? Typically I see Call-Stack data when an exception is thrown. In this case, the application runs with no exception. How can I still see a call stack or something similar to understand what happens to every request?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print the current Stack Trace in .NET without any exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531695/how-to-print-the-current-stack-trace-in-net-without-any-exception)

Comment: `new StackTrace()` ought to do it.

Comment: I think what you're really after is the execution flow, there's no error's but instead of stepping through the code (and Ctrl + Alt + C to see the Call Stack isn't suffice?) you want to see a call stack. A few suggestions, 1) An AOP library and wrap methods with Attributes (a potential fork of the repo), 2) use the VS tool called [Debugger Canvas](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DebuggerCanvasTeam.DebuggerCanvas) or 3) [like me hack something together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326673/user-activity-logging-telemetry-and-variables-in-global-exception-handlers)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415084/is-there-a-tool-for-visual-studio-which-can-show-the-list-of-all-called-function